# Add a label to the center of a polygon in kml

Tags: kml, leaflet, mapquest

Can anyone tell me how I would add a label to the center of a polygon by way of kml like the ones in the link: http://maps.huge.info/zip.htm.. I don't want a marker and I don't need the info to pop up when its clicked, I need it to be there from load, it would just have the zip code for the particular polygon. I wont be drawing the entire US zip code, maybe just a few at a time. Oh, and I'm using mapquest API not google or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) plugin, that does exactly this.